# Hangfire - Recurring job with specified queue name

Tags: hangfire

I have two server, ServerA and ServerB. They share the same hangfire database.
I have two jobs, JobA and JobB.

On ServerA, I use:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
            "JobA",
            () => new JobA().Execute(),
            this._configuration.Schedule, queue: "A");
```

On ServerB, I use:

```
  RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
            "JobB",
            () => new JobB().Execute(),
            this._configuration.Schedule, queue: "B");
```

The problem is that each jobs is "Enqueued" in the "Job" table, they are never executed.

If I remove the queue override in the "AddOrUpdate" method, jobs are executed (obviously without queue configured).

Something missing? How configure recurring jobs with queue configuration?

Answer (score 3):

Code was missing...

ServerA:

```
var options = new BackgroundJobServerOptions
            {
                Queues = new[] { "A" }
            };

            this._backgroundJobServer = new BackgroundJobServer(options);
```

ServerB:

```
var options = new BackgroundJobServerOptions
            {
                Queues = new[] { "B" }
            };

            this._backgroundJobServer = new BackgroundJobServer(options);
```

Comment: I am using hangfire 1.5.6. I have a similar issue - Did you find out the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Solution - might help someone with similar issue:

```
app.UseHangfireServer(new BackgroundJobServerOptions
{
     // queue name must be in lowercase
     Queues = new[] { "qname" } //This will setup the server to only process qname queues 
});

RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
    () => new JobB().Execute(),
    Cron.Hourly(5),
    null,
    "qname");
```